# Can't install PySimpleGUI on PyCharm

Tags: python, pycharm, pysimplegui

I am trying to install PySimpleGUI on PyCharm on my Mac (MacOS 13.0.1). Both recommended ways of installation are not working:

When I try to install through Settings > Python Interpreter > + > PySimpleGUI > Install Package

I get this message:

```
Error occurred when installing package 'PySimpleGUI'.
```

It then recommends trying to install by running the pip command in the terminal. When I run the pip and pip3 command in the terminal I get this message:

```
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:992)'))': /simple/pysimplegui/
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/pysimplegui/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/pysimplegui/ (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:992)'))) - skipping
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement PySimpleGUI (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for PySimpleGUI
```

If someone is able to identify the problem please let me know

I've tried to watch youtube tutorials and read posts on here for an answer to this issue but I couldn't find anything specifically answering this question for me.

Comment: https://github.com/PySimpleGUI/PySimpleGUI/issues/5471#issuecomment-1426888530

Comment: Just tried that, I get this return: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python: can't open file '/Users/elipolini/Desktop/Python App 1/3.X/Install': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Comment: It turns out that cyber security software I have on my computer was blocking the download.

Comment: I don't have Mac platform for it, just found the reference for you.